# Quantifying change size in a deploy

Tags: metrics

In this presentation, slide 79 plots TTR and Lines of code changed
http://www.slideshare.net/fullscreen/jallspaw/ops-metametrics-the-currency-you-pay-for-change/79

From what I've read, lines of code changed is a poor indicator of how much the code base actually changed functionally.

What are some other metrics to use as a way to quantify the degree of change in a deploy

Comment: "Change" by itself doesn't mean anything. Degree of change of _what_? What are you trying to measure, and what for?

Comment: Degree of change in the codebase. That slide seems to indicate that the more lines of code changed the higher the Time to recovery is when there is an issue. Therefore, we are better off making smaller changes in a single deploy. I'm wondering if there are any other measurements related to change in the codebase that would show a correlation with TTR. For example, # of modules where code was changed within a deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no well established, reliable methods for quantifying change in a deploy.  There are metrics you can use like lines of code, size of binary, number of checkins, and number of fixed bugs.  None of them by themselves are consistent indicators of quality or volatility, but they may serve as rough indicators at a large enough scale.